# Inserting Data in Sql table from a Stream of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, sql, .net-4.0

I want to find a way to populate a DB SQL table directly from a Stream of bytes. 
I constructed a MemoryStream and now I would like to use this data to populate a table. 
Example of file loaded in MemoryStream:

```
row1|1|1|1|1
row2|2|2|2|2
row3|3|3|3|3
row4|4|4|4|4
```

I would like to identify the | as a column seaparator and the \n as a row separator. I found a way of doing this using a DataAdaptor but I am not sure how to use it. Can anyone guide me through the process?

```
private void Insert(MemoryStream src,string provider, string table)
    {
       // code to populate the table
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is Sql Server:

```
using(var c = new SqlConnection(provider))
{
 c.Open();
 using(var sc = c.CreateCommand())
 {
  sc.CommandText = "INSERT "+table+" VALUES(@data)";
  sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", src.ToArray());
  sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid copying the Stream again. As you see you call src.ToArray() and copy the stream into an Array.